# how do you process many files without running out of memory in R

Tags: r

I am trying to parse thousands of files in a directory. I wrote this script to go thought each file but my system is going out of memory. How else I can process these files?

```
dir_path<-c("C:/Documents/Data")
input_files <- list.files(path = input_path, pattern = "htm",  full.names = TRUE)
nn = length(input_files)
total_data = data.table(server = as.character(), time = as.character())
for(i in 1:nn)
  { 
     xmlobj = xmlTreeParse(file = input_files[i],  isHTML = T)
     r = xmlRoot(xmlobj)
     server = xmlValue(r[[2]][1][1]$h1)
     time = xmlValue(r[[2]][4][1]$dl[1]$dt)
     web_data = rbind(web_data, data.frame(server, time))
     total_data<-rbind(web_data, total_data)
     gc()

  }
```

Each file I am reading has this content. The files in htm format:

Apache Server Status for webserver101

```
Server Version: IBM_HTTP_Server/7.0.0.39 (Unix)
Server Built: Aug 3 2015 17:29:08 

Current Time: Sunday, 05-Jun-2016 13:56:27 EDT
Restart Time: Saturday, 04-Jun-2016 23:06:02 EDT
Parent Server Generation: 0
Server uptime: 14 hours 50 minutes 24 seconds
Total accesses: 39855 - Total Traffic: 1.2 GB
CPU Usage: u814.13 s13.33 cu0 cs0 - 1.55% CPU load.746 
requests/sec - 24.2 kB/second - 32.5 kB/request7 
requests currently being processed, 73 idle workers
```

Comment: What do you do after you have processed a file?

Comment: @Zheyuan, I read each file and take out what I want and form a data frame and keep adding the data from each file to a data frame. This should work but my system running out of memory.

Comment: Well, how big is your `data.frame` object getting?    Meanwhile, there are packages designed to write large objects to file transparently; you might track those down.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi `gc()` is almost never necessary. That's not a good place to start.

Comment: @Zheyuan, I just added the whole think what I'm trying to do.

Comment: [try to avoid growing objects](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#chapter.2)

Comment: gc() is not helping either. Is there a way to process these files in chunks of 1000's?

Comment: you should try to know the final size of `web_data` and then you can just fill the place that corresponds to the current data and avoid all this memory gluttony

Comment: @Cath, web_data is very small, it has 2 data points. There are 21,000 files, each file I process has 2 data points. I am processing each file, adding the values to total_data data frame and removing object after each file. Not sure why running out of memory.

Comment: each of your files has only 2 data points ? I'm not familiar with the functions you're using to import the data in R but maybe try to import the files in a list ? could you show how your files look like ?

Comment: I've updated the post. Rather that going through 21,000 files, is there a way to split this 21,000 into 1000 and process 1000 files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115126/discussion-between-cath-and-user1471980).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try importing all your files in a list and then processing the list:

```
all_files <- lapply(input_files, xmlTreeParse, isHTML=TRUE)
process_files <- lapply(all_files, function(myfile){
    r = xmlRoot(xmlobj)
    server = xmlValue(r[[2]][1][1]$h1)
    time = xmlValue(r[[2]][4][1]$dl[1]$dt)
    web_data = data.frame(server, time, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    web_data
}
total_data <- do.call(rbind, process_files)
```

if you need to split your data in chunks, you can use the function `seq` to get the beginning indices of the chunks:

```
seq_ind <- seq(1, length(input_files), by=1000)
```

Then you can get the list of the files corresponding to each chunk with

```
files_in_chunks <- mapply(function(x, y) input_files[x:y], x=seq_ind, y=c(seq_ind[-1], length(input_files)), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```